# Magento Connect Manager: Strange Symbols/Characters

Tags: magento

I'm getting some really strange characters & symbols (see below) appearing inside the magento connect manager - at the top at first, but then moves to below 'manage existing extension' after click 'check for upgrades'.

I haven't actually tried to add any extensions or make any changes due to concerns about this and I just wanted to know whether this should be a concern?

& if it is, how to go about fixing it?

> Mac OS X   2��ATTR��G�Gcom.apple.quarantineq/0003;55658415;The\x20Unarchiver;A9545E3F-A779-45B7-976C-E4D2F1D74415Mac OS X  2��ATTR��G�Gcom.apple.quarantineq/0003;55658415;The\x20Unarchiver;CDF98C36-7D2A-4022-B411-49CFFCAFB994Mac OS X  2��ATTR��G�Gcom.apple.quarantineq/0003;55658415;The\x20Unarchiver;7D754489-9B3F-402D-BBD5-954527086E18Mac OS X  2��ATTR��G�Gcom.apple.quarantineq/0003;55658415;The\x20Unarchiver;EBA519DC-C3F0-4774-848C-69828D048757Mac OS X  2��ATTR��G�Gcom.apple.quarantineq/0003;55658415;The\x20Unarchiver;D8E4CEED-920A-4319-94E7-8C2DF812E358Mac OS X  2��ATTR��G�Gcom.apple.quarantineq/0003;55658415;The\x20Unarchiver;2B3B1EBF-5C2F-46D0-9464-B05FB82F676C

Comment: Googling one of the messages brought up [this blog post](http://entropytc.com/got-com-apple-quarantine-problems/), did you already try that? Perhaps you just downloaded The Unarchiver application?

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your server and go to the following folder:

`[magento root folder]/downloader/lib/Mage/Connect/Command`

remove all the dot underscore files with this command: `rm ._*`